# What about a sort button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

As I login to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, I browse through the list of newest questions. Some are answered, some are unanswered, some are put on hold, some are duplicate ... and I look up, and I cry out : "Where the hell is the sort button ?!"

Seriously, a sort button would be a good feature for this site. Then, helpful people (like me. :) ) can see which newest questions are unanswered, moderators can see which questions are put on hold and review them again, bounty-hunters can search for questions with a high bounty and answer them, etc. (I know that there are tabs which contain all these grouped into specific categories, but, a sort feature within these tabs would be damn good...)

It would simplify everyone's life... Okay, well maybe not everyone, but almost everyone who browses through Android Enthusiasts with one or the other question. I might not have thought about the amount of code that goes into implementing that feature, and I might not know how tough it is to do so, I might not know the amount of scoldings the wives of those people who code it might give them for coming home late: ( :) ) but hey, it is cool after all, right? If any of the statements above are in any way hurting anyone, please mention it to me, and I'll edit them out. But, think of it. I'm REALLY for this feature's implementation. What about you?

Comment: Pinging people in comments only works if they've actually participated in the comment section of a post, otherwise they receive no notifications (very much intentional design).  When people have time and desire to weigh in, they will generally do so. No need to clutter up things with all the random comments.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about that. Sorry.

Comment: As far as the specifics of this feature request: it sounds like the search system may accomplish a good chunk of what you're looking for. You can sort any search by votes, date posted or last activity date. You can also put together some pretty specific searches, like some of your examples: [closed questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=is+question+closed%3A1),  [unanswered questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=is+question++isanswered%3A1) Are there other sorting criteria you'd like to see?

Comment: @eldarerathis, I mean to say that there should be like a 'Sort newest to oldest' feature, or a 'Sort by status (Answered first, Unanswered later) ' or a 'Sort by Views' or something like that everywhere, in search, in tabs, in meta too. That was what I meant to ask.

Comment: There already is a "newest" tab everywhere.  Sorting by "answered first" is not useful since you'll get many thousands of answered questions before every seeing an unanswered question, so you might as well look at answered-only.  I can't see a way to sort by views, which would probably be useful (so I think it should be added) within a narrow search -- otherwise it will just show old popular questions which you can get by filtering by `views:superhighnumber` anyways.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I feel that sorting by 'answered first' will help users to see whether a similar question to their question already has an answer.

Answer (score 4):

> which newest questions are unanswered

https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answered%3a0

> which questions are put on hold

https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1

> questions with a high bounty

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured

There is simply no way to include every possible search combination as a UI filter, it would be insanely cluttered and completely unusable.

If you want to search for a narrower subset of questions instead of a broad category, that's exactly what search is for and what it's good at.  A huge list of filters in the UI is just going to slow you down.

You should take a look at https://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching and familiarize yourself with the search operators you find most useful!